# Nav remove sticky logo text (SVG) in Elementor

Tags: css, elementor

Is there any way how to remove the Nav logo text from sticky Nav while scrolling in elementor Pro?. The logo is in SVG format?.

[image]

Comment: Do you know ID or Class of the element?

Comment: Yes off course.

Comment: So What is the ID or Class?

Comment: The class name is "elementor-element-73be40f"

Comment: Can you add custom CSS to your project?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour yes offcourse

Comment: Please did my answer work? Please respond?

Comment: No. I used js Affix for this now it works correctly. Thank you for your comments and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove nav stick logo try :

```css
.elementor-element-73be40f {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I have also added `!important` property to force CSS to remove the element.